# Abbreviations for organizations in Esperanto texts - in Esperanto or English?

Tags: translation, abbreviations

When translating, the goal is to make the content understood. Therefore, we would usually translate everything into Esperanto. However, another issue is being able to follow up on what the text is about. When we talk about organizations like the UN or UNESCO or the IPCC, when should/shouldn't I use Esperanto abbreviations? 
UN and UNESKO are easy, but the European Youth Forum is FOJE and the IPCC is the ISKŜ. 
If the abbreviations are "google-able" then I'd use the Esperanto ones, otherwise I'd stick with the English/French/commonly known version from other languages.

Answer (score 1):

I would stick to the English abbreviations and "spell them out" in Esperanto the first time you use them.

Comment: I second to that, but do NOT use English abbreviations for Esperanto organisations.